# How to achieve maximum web security here

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, ssl

We have a browser front end that communicates with a Node.js server which stores data in a MongoDB database in a BlueMix cloud.

My bosses really don't want data being seen by intruders. None of us are security experts. We thought it would be a good idea to establish an SSL connection, using the certificate to ensure the browser is communicating with a trusted website and SSL encryption to protect the communication.

In addition, my boss wants data stored in the DB to be encrypted. This would mean a second layer of encryption. Data submitted by the browser would pass through SSL, get encrypted by the server, and then stored in the Mongo DB. If the browser wants that data, the server will retrieve it but won't bother to decrypt it first.

Basically the browser logs in and if successful, the server responds with a private key that can be used to decrypt the data on the browser end. This key would be stored in a JS variable.

This way when an intruder retrieves data from the Mongo DB, they only see encrypted gibberish if they don't have the key (they didn't long in first). Or worse, if they manage to hack into the DB.

Would this be a good way to give our customers peace of mind that their info is really being protected?

Help grealy appreciated

Comment: How could a non logged in user get the data in the first place? Decrypting it on the client is just asking for slowness.

Comment: Say a browser wants to retrieve info for a profile ID. The server retrieves the info and returns it encrypted. The non-logged in user would only see gibberish they couldn't decrypt.

Comment: A non logged in user should not be able to get any data in the first place. If they are getting data, than you already have a security hole. The server should be returning 401 or 403.

Comment: If the request is not accompanied by a secure cookie indicating a valid (logged-in) session, the server should not return anything in the first place. That's how secured sites work.

Comment: Well the server only sees HTTP requests it doesn't know if the requests are coming from an interface or a request cobbled together by an intruder

Comment: If nobody involved with implementing your site knows anything about security, it's wildly unethical to *advertise* it as secure.

Comment: @Wes it doesn't matter - either the request has a valid unforgeable session cookie, or it doesn't.

Comment: What would be stored in that cookie?

Comment: *"Well the server only sees HTTP requests"* That is how the web typically works. Do you understand basics of cookie and cookieless sessions?

Comment: @Wes the session cookie should contain a long cryptographically-secure random value constructed uniquely for a single login session. Most server-side frameworks provide a session management mechanism.

Comment: What is that value used for?

Comment: I never claimed to be an expert here, not sure why people are acting like I have. I am a security dummy. They came to me with their problem I can't help that.

Comment: @Wes it's used to prove that the request is associated with a valid session. Your server-side framework knows what values correspond with valid sessions. The random numbers are large enough that they are effectively impossible to guess. This is all very basic "how secure sites work" information; don't try to invent your own security protocols.

Comment: Alrighty thanks for your help without bombarding you with a million more dumb questions I will some more research first

Comment: @Wes I understand your situation and I don't mean to attack you, but you have to know that what you're being asked to do is unethical. If your boss asked you to implement a flight control system for a helicopter, would you do that if you didn't know anything about how helicopters work?

Comment: You may be right I will tell my superiors what I have discovered here.

Comment: @Wes, All there is to be said : http://xkcd.com/538/ Good luck explaining that to your boss ;)

Answer (score -2):

your solution seems perfect, if you are looking for some more security, then better idea is to hide your nodejs server url from front end, if its possible in your case try to add another middle ware which will work as bridge between nodejs server and front end. End users if some how checks the page source then they won't be getting your actual nodejs server location.

Comment: No, it's absolutely not perfect; it's *terrible*.